# Rails - Purpose of using respond_to if templates are available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have seen some people using code like this

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
end
```

What is the purpose of this if we have template.html and template.js. Either can be rendered without specifying respond_to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your snippet doesn't do anything special, but the formatting options allow you to provide additional custom behavior if it is necessary.

For example, if you want to render your `@products` as a JSON:

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js { render :json => @products }
end
```

This is just one of the many things you can do with the format blocks. For more information, see [Ruby on Rails Guides: Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

The format options can take a block so that you can do some custom rendering such as rendering a file or `:head` response. Have a look at some of the examples [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify different behavior for the different formats there is no reason to use `respond_to`. If you have templates they will automatically be picked up by rails. The `respond_to` method is useful if you need different behavior per format:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :edit }
  format.json { render :json => '{}' }
end
```